# ssh_config, host section for servers in search domain

Tags: ssh

I have test.example.com in my DNS search domains. When I `ssh server01`, it connects to my server as expected. However it doesn't follow my ssh_config rules because it doesn't match:

```
Host *.test.example.com 
User djimenez
ForwardAgent yes
```

No problem, I'll add a wild card!

```
Host *
User djimenez
ForwardAgent yes
```

However, this applies to every host. Not just short DNS names (non-FQDN, if you will).

My question, is there anyway to create a host rule that matches only short dns names? Or even better, would be if there was some magic way for ssh to get the FQDN from DNS (in case I have several search domains).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only two wildcards allowed in a *Host* specification are `*` which matches any string, and `?` which matches any single character. You can also prepend `!` to a pattern to negate the sense of the match, so that it applies to host values which don't match the rest of the pattern.

So, a rule like this:

```
Host !*.*
    SomeOption...
```

should apply to any hostname value that doesn't contain a period.

You can also have more than one pattern per *Host* line, in case you want the rules to apply to the long form of the hostnames:

```
Host !*.* *.test.example.com
    SomeOption...
```

Comment: You got me very close. Ultimately I wanted `Host * !*.*`. Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't think the second suggestion (mixing the negated entry and pattern works), because according to the `ssh_config` man page `If a negated entry is matched, then the Host entry is ignored, regardless of whether any other patterns on the line match`, so attempting to access `host-01.test.example.com` will not match the block because it is "excluded" by the `!*.*` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The `ssh_config` man-page states: "The host is the hostname argument given on the command line (i.e. the name is not converted to a canonicalized host name before matching)."

A way around it would be to create a wrapper script that first expands the hostname you provide to a FQDN, if possible, and then pass that to ssh, see e.g. https://serverfault.com/questions/567272/expand-hostnames-to-fqdn-before-calling-ssh